# how to get json response from google custom search Api

Tags: php, google-api

Actually i want to search question from google and its answer
for example

question

what is definition of astrology.
answer

the study of the movements and relative positions of celestial bodies interpreted as having an influence on human affairs and the natural world.

like that i want from this api
how it is possible

```
 $search_query = $this->input->post('search');
    $url ="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyD7Ho22AiuqaieQmg1GyMP9HxvID0V0VWg&cx=003432080158696714251:n4rbif5gizk&q='$search_query'";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$results = json_decode($json);

if ($results->searchInformation->totalResults) {
    $resutItems = $results->items;
    // do whatever with the result
}
```